# How to show product custom attribute in items ordered section in magento2.2.0?

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes

How to show product custom attribute with values in items ordered section in magento2.2.0?
Refer screenshot[image]

The above image is my custom attribute(PCB Master)[image]

In the above image i need to show my custom attribute with its value under SKU in magento2.2.0

Comment: Does it user input?

Comment: No, the admin adds it from backend

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To overwrite any adminhtml template file you need to create custom module. For you order item section changes I have overwrite vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml in to my module.

First of all create etc/module.xml file. Below is the code for module.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Darsh_Orderitem" setup_version="1.0.0" >      
    </module>
</config>
```

Create view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml file in your module. In this file I have used "referenceBlock" tag to overwrite core template file and used "setTemplate" method.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">    
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="default_order_items_renderer">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Darsh_Orderitem::order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now, create phtml file in your folder view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php /** @var \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items\Renderer\DefaultRenderer $block */ ?>
<?php $_item = $block->getItem() ?>
<?php 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory')->create()->load($_item->getProductId());
?>
<?php $block->setPriceDataObject($_item) ?>
<tr>
    <?php $i = 0;
    $columns = $block->getColumns();
    $lastItemNumber = count($columns) ?>
    <?php foreach ($columns as $columnName => $columnClass):?>
        <?php $i++; ?>
        <td class="<?= /* @noEscape */ $columnClass ?><?= /* @noEscape */ ($i === $lastItemNumber ? ' last' : '') ?>"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getColumnHtml($_item, $columnName) ?>
            <?php if($columnClass == "col-product"){  ?>
                <span><?php echo __("PCB:") ?></span>
                    <?php echo $product->getData('pcb_master');; ?> 
                <?php  } ?>
        </td>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</tr>
```

In phtml file I have load product data and get "pcb_master" attribute value.

If you still you are facing issue then you can download module from https://github.com/Darshanmodi1427/Orderitem

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Amy, Is my answer helpful to you or still facing issue?  If it is helpful then please up vote.

Comment: Hi Darsh, yesterday i was on leave so i am checking now. i will let you know ASAP. Thanks:)

Comment: Hi Darsh i have applied your module. but nothing is shown. Is there any problem creating the module

Comment: You have download module from Git ? I have checked it was working fine. https://github.com/Darshanmodi1427/Orderitem

Comment: Yes Darsh, i have downloaded from your link only. But i am not able to identify what's the mistake.

Comment: check with step by step.
First check, you have removed all your old code ?<br/>
Then, check Extension installed properly and run setup:upgrade, setup:static-content:de<br/>
Check order item section additional row display or not.<br/> 
check "pcb_master" attribute created and order item has value in "pcb_master" field.<br/>
Might be you will find solution :)

Comment: @Darshmodi nice work  :)

Comment: @Darshmodi thanks for your module. It is working fine, but for some reason, the attribute code is not shown. I mean, the field is shown, but the value not. Do you have any suggestions? I'm using Magento 2.3.3

Comment: Hi, @Darshmodi this works like a charm but what if I have to show custom order attribute somewhere else, I mean maybe in under Shipping & Handling Information